# SP 2016 Page with list of SiteCollections that users have access too

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

So, I have a SharePoint 2016 on-prem site that has 10 site collections under it.  Different users have access to various site collections, and that is all handled in AD.  I'd like to set up the home page of the overall site and  display to each user the sites that have permissions to access. Is something like this possible?  Appreciate any pointers...

Comment: Do you mean that the main site collection is associeted to 10 additional site collections, or is it 10 sub sites?

Comment: Yes, a main site collection with 10 additional site collections under it.  On that main site collection, I then want the visitors to see links to the sites they have access to via an AD group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello use **Search Content Query Web-Part** and as filter use `contentclass:STS_Site`. It will display all sites, but you know, search is using permission-based filtering, so users will see only Sites where they have permissions.

You'll probably need to filter Path to, cause they should be displayed unwanted Site Collections as MySites, so use `Path:https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/*`

[MS Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/building-search-queries-in-sharepoint)